# Class member function as a template parameter in case of inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

How to pass a function pointer as a template parameter if function is implemented in base class.

```cpp
template<class T, int(T::* FUNC)() const>
int TestFunc(const T& _v)
{
    return (_v.*FUNC)();
}

struct A
{
    int F() const   { return 100; }
};

struct B : public A {};

int main()
{
    B b;
    int32_t value = TestFunc<B, &B::F>(b);
    cout << value;
    //...
}
```

Get an error C2672: 'TestFunc': no matching overloaded function found.

In case of VS compiler static_cast helps:

```
typedef int(B::* BF)() const;
int32_t value = TestFunc<B, static_cast<BF>(&B::F)>(b);
```

These are built and run successfully, but i need to build it with clang.

Any ideas?

P.S. `BF bf = &B::F;` this conversion works without casts, so compiler understands class `B` has method `F`. But it does not work as a template argument.

Update: P.P.S. Actual classes and code are more sophisticated. Above example is just a very simplified version to outline the problem.

Workaround: current workaround i've used is to override F() in B class which just calls inherited, but still looking for a better solution.

Comment: No idea, but perhaps you could find something interesting [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to just use `A` as the template parameter:

```
int32_t value = TestFunc<A, &A::F>(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly specify both template arguments in the call, may be you can let the compiler deduce the member function type for you:

```
template<class T, class P>
int TestFunc(const T& _v, P p) {
    return (_v.*p)();
}
```

And then:

```
int32_t value = TestFunc(b, &B::F);
```

Comment: In actual code instead of TestFunc is a large class and FUNC is used in about dosen of functions. And this class is then inherited by serveral other classes. Suggested solution will require a lot of refactoring :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it wont work as is.

There are possible workarounds:

- The one from @Maxim Egorushkin
- Another is to use additional template function wrapper which takes B& and calls F inside:

```
    template<class T, int(*FUNC)(const T&) const>
    int TestFunc(const T& _v)
    {
        return (*FUNC)(_v);
    }

    template <class T>
    int F_Wrapper(const T& obj)
    {
        return obj.F();
    }

    ...

    int value = TestFunc < B, &F_Wrapper<B>>(b);
```

- But still the easiest is to override F function inside B class.